# Find NSRanges of all substrings splitted by new lines

Tags: swift, string, nsrange

So I have this code finding `Range`s substrings by splitting new lines:

```
let string = "hello\nhello"
let rangesSplittedByLines: [Range] = string.split(separator: "\n").compactMap {
    return string.range(of: $0)
}
```

But I need those ranges as `NSRange`.
How would you get `NSRange` array of all substrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the closure create an `NSRange` from `Range<String.Index>`

```
let string = "hello\nhello"
let rangesSplittedByLines: [NSRange] = string.split(separator: "\n").map {
    return NSRange(string.range(of: $0)!, in: string)
}
```

But there is another problem. The code returns `[{0, 5}, {0, 5}]` because `range(of:` returns always the range of the **first** match.

This fixes the problem, it slices the string by moving the start index to the position after the most recent match

```
let string = "hello\nhello"
var startIndex = string.startIndex
let rangesSplittedByLines: [NSRange] = string.split(separator: "\n").map {
    let subString = string[startIndex...]
    let swiftRange = subString.range(of: $0)!
    let nsRange = NSRange(swiftRange, in: string)
    startIndex = swiftRange.upperBound
    return nsRange
}
```

And there is no reason to bridge `String` to `NSString` explicitly.

But as you want *nsranges* anyway Regular Expression like in Martin’s answer is much more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of splitting the string and “reconstructing” the ranges you can use a regular expression matching which returns the ranges directly. The `[^\n]+` pattern matches one or more characters which are not the newline character. Example:

```
let string = "hello\nhello"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: #"[^\n]+"#)
let matches = regex.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(string.startIndex..., in: string))
let ranges = matches.map { $0.range }

print(ranges) // [{0, 5}, {6, 5}
```